# Realm migration race condition

Tags: objective-c, swift, migration, realm, race-condition

How can I guarantee that realm migrations will finish before accessing realm? There seems to be a race condition in migrating a realm db and beginning to read/write to the realm. Here's my issue:

Currently I am setting the realm configurations with a migration closure when a user launches the app. Once the realm configuration has been set with RLMRealmConfiguration.setDefaultConfiguration(config), I set the RootViewController and begin accessing realm data.

However, when a migration is needed, realm is sometimes accessed before the migrations can complete - causing a crash (RLMException: Object has been deleted or invalidated). If a migration is an async task with no callback, how can we guarantee that it finishes before accessing realm?

Here's my realm config code:

```
 class func SetRealmConfigurationForUser(userId: String) {
    let config = RLMRealmConfiguration.defaultConfiguration()

    // migration setup
    config.schemaVersion = 10
    config.migrationBlock = { migration, oldSchemaVersion in
        if oldSchemaVersion < 2 {
            migration.enumerateObjects(ContactUser.className()) { oldObject, newObject in
                // Change primary key from PhoneNumber to Phone_BaseId_Key
                let phone = oldObject?["PhoneNumber"]
                let baseId = oldObject?["BaseId"]

                newObject?["Phone_BaseId_Key"] = String(phone) + "_" + String(baseId)
            }
        }
        if oldSchemaVersion < 3 {
            migration.enumerateObjects(DigitsContact.className()) { oldObject, newObject in
                newObject?["ExternalId"] = ""
            }
        }
        if oldSchemaVersion < 9 {
            migration.deleteDataForClassName(DigitsContact.className())
            migration.deleteDataForClassName(Address.className())
            migration.deleteDataForClassName(Email.className())
            migration.deleteDataForClassName(PhoneNumber.className())
        }
    }

    // Use default directory, but replace filename with the userId
    config.path = (((config.path! as NSString).stringByDeletingLastPathComponent as NSString)
                                            .stringByAppendingPathComponent(userId) as NSString)
                                            .stringByAppendingPathExtension("realm")
    RLMRealmConfiguration.setDefaultConfiguration(config)
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [Realm's Migrations docs](https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/#migrations), migrations are only applied when opening a `Realm` with the configuration on which the schema version and migration blocks are set:

> When creating a Realm with this configuration, the migration block will be applied to update the Realm to the given schema version if a migration is needed.

So if you're calling `SetRealmConfigurationForUser` *asynchronously*, any concurrent Realm accesses will use the previous default configuration and not see the migration block that you're in the process of defining.

Performing a migration always happens synchronously, by either implicitly by creating the Realm with a migration block in its configuration or explicitly by calling [`RLMRealm.migrateRealm(_:)`](https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/api/Classes/RLMRealm.html#/c:objc(cs)RLMRealm(cm)migrateRealm:).

All other Realm accesses (both reads & writes) will be blocked on the migration completing. So as long as the migration block & configuration are set before any Realm is initialized, there should be no race condition.

PS: You're doing a lot of wasted work in your migration block when `oldSchema < 3` because you're setting all your `DigitsContact.ExternalId` properties to `""`, only to then delete all the `DigitsContact` objects. Just removing the `oldSchemaVersion < 3` conditional and its contents will lead to the same result.

PPS: Is there a reason you're using Realm Objective-C from Swift rather than Realm Swift? Realm has a dedicated API that's much nicer to use from Swift: https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/

Comment: SetRealmConfigurationForUser is called synchronously so it must be that a Realm is accessed before it gets called. I'm now suspecting that this is happening in a singleton since Realm could not be accessed otherwise until after SetRealmConfigurationForUser. Thank you, this makes more sense. Also, I am using the Obj-C Realm since the project is a mix of Swift and Obj-C.

Comment: And just to clarify: even though setDefaultConfiguration gets called before the migrationBlock finishes, Realm will block all accesses until migrationBlock does finish?